# How to remove autocompletions for Monaco Editor using Javascript?

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm embedding the Monaco Editor in my App, I have some javascript files that should not show completions for "Web" environments (think Node.js or similar)  I would like to have completions appear for only the functions and classes that are defined on the page.

How do I remove all the "Web" autocompletions from the javascript mode?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is a great question. This Github issue covers the same topic: https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/61.

According to that, disabling the built-in library is done by passing noLib to setCompilerOptions:

```
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({ noLib: true, allowNonTsExtensions: true });
```

You can add additional typings by using addExtraLib, which hangs off of the javascriptDefaults. Typescript provides some d.ts files that provide the basics for ES5 and ES6, without the browser cruft. Download one of them and find a way to include it in your project. You will need to pass it in as a string.

```
var coreDefsName = 'lib.es5.d.ts';

// Import the text of your chosen def file.  This will depend on your bundler.
var coreDefs = getResourceString('./' + coreDefsName);

// Register the additional library.
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(
coreDefs,
coreDefsName
);
```

Comment: When I set this, it gives me `Could not find file: 'inmemory://model/1`

Comment: This works: `setCompilerOptions({ noLib: true, allowNonTsExtensions: true})`

Comment: getResourceString is not defined.

Answer (score 5):

There is another way other than `noLibs`. You can also use `libs` to define the default libs you want without removing **all** of the default libs. For example, you may still want the ES6 lib.

```
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
  target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES2015,
  lib: ["es6"]
});
```

From the Typescript docs in the CompilerOptions section:

> Note:
>
> If --lib is not specified a default list of libraries are injected. The 
>   default libraries injected are: 
>   For --target ES5: DOM,ES5,ScriptHost
>   For --target ES6: DOM,ES6,DOM.Iterable,ScriptHost

What you probably want to do is omit the `DOM` library.

Make sure you use `typescriptDefaults` for the `typescript` language and `typescript.javascriptDefaults` for the `javascript` language. I think they are basically equivalent with Monaco. This had tripped me up for a while.

Comment: This no longer works. When options like that are set, no completion items are shown at all. Only the "Loading..." entry stays forever.

Comment: `lib: ["es6"]` was still including DOM definitions for me, but changing it to `lib: ['es2015']` worked https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#lib

Answer (score 2):

If you are using it in React JS using this library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@monaco-editor/

**import Editor from "@monaco-editor/react"**

Then you can write down below points to make changes in the Editor's behaviours:

```
<Editor
  height="90vh"
  defaultLanguage="javascript"
  defaultValue={code}
  options={{
    quickSuggestions: {
      other: false,
      comments: false,
      strings: false
    },
    parameterHints: {
      enabled: false
    },
    suggestOnTriggerCharacters: false,
    acceptSuggestionOnEnter: "off",
    tabCompletion: "off",
    wordBasedSuggestions: false
  }}
/>
```

To see the list of possible options please check [IStandaloneEditorConstructionOptions](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.istandaloneeditorconstructionoptions.html)

Answer (score 0):

for those that need to disable default libs and provide their libs, you could disable default libs by **noLib** option

```
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
  target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES2015,
  noLib: true, 
  allowNonTsExtensions: true,
  checkJs: true,
  strict: true,
  allowJs: true,
});
```

then go [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/main/lib)
to download lib that you prefer, reduce file and keep what you want then export file content as a const sring

```
export const es5String = `interface Array<T> {
/**
 * Returns the value of the first element in the array where predicate is true, and undefined
 * otherwise.
 * @param predicate find calls predicate once for each element of the array, in ascending
 * order, until it finds one where predicate returns true. If such an element is found, find
 * immediately returns that element value. Otherwise, find returns undefined.
 * @param thisArg If provided, it will be used as the this value for each invocation of
 * predicate. If it is not provided, undefined is used instead.
 */
find<S extends T>(predicate: (this: void, value: T, index: number, obj: T[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S | undefined;
find(predicate: (value: T, index: number, obj: T[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): T | undefined;
.......
.......
```

finally import that string and use it as custom extra lib, something like this

```
import { es5String } from "./es5Custom.core"

monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
  target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES2015,
  noLib: true, 
  allowNonTsExtensions: true,
  checkJs: true,
  strict: true,
  allowJs: true,
});

monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(
  es5String,
  "filename/es5.d.ts"
);
```

you could add your custom libs also.