# Adding custom limited Javascript autocomplete set to Monaco editor with addExtraLib

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, monaco-editor

I would like to limit the amount of suggestions Monaco gives me on default with plain Javascript. Things like autocompleting array object's properties such as length are welcome but anything related to DOM or CSS elements is not needed.

There's a Github issue reply that describes [how this can be achieved](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1001#issuecomment-413519664) in theory, but there's an issue ran into with the approach described in the link. The custom definitions for JS such as [lib.es5.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.es5.d.ts) are so long that if I try to convert the whole definition to Javascript string and feed to Monaco through `monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(libSource, libUri);` function, Javascript crashes to `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` because the string containing the definitions is too long to process.

Is there a way to configure Monaco so that only lib.es5.d.ts definitions are being used with autocomplete, or perhaps some way around the too long string issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove autocompletions for Monaco Editor using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41581570/how-to-remove-autocompletions-for-monaco-editor-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by using a webpack raw-loader to import the definitions as a js handle and then passing that handle to `monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setExtraLibs(...)` function appropriately. Many different definitions can be included this way.

Comment: What does "appropriately? mean, though? Hopefully you can show a bit more code than `(...)` that shows the actual syntax that solved the problem so others (including me =) can learn from that.