# How to remove default DOM/Browser related autocompletions for Monaco Editor using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I'm using Monaco for JavaScript object literal creation, where I need just the basic type completion, plus a custom one (using monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('javascript', ...)).

[image: Default JavaScript autocompletion]

When I use the recommended solution in [How to remove autocompletions for Monaco Editor using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41581570/how-to-remove-autocompletions-for-monaco-editor-using-javascript) :

```
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions(
  { noLib: true, allowNonTsExtensions: false}
)
```

...the result is much better:

[image: Only custom autocompletion]

... but now the developer console shows a continuous flow of uncaught errors when I interact with the Monaco Editor:

```
tsMode.js:8 
        
       Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not find source file: 'inmemory://model/2'.
    at ln (tsWorker.js:250)
    at Object.sn [as getSyntacticDiagnostics] (tsWorker.js:250)
    at pm.getSyntacticDiagnostics (tsWorker.js:35306)
    at w.fmr (workerMain.js:17)
    at s._handleMessage (workerMain.js:13)
    at Object.handleMessage (workerMain.js:13)
    at m._handleRequestMessage (workerMain.js:13)
    at m._handleMessage (workerMain.js:13)
    at m.handleMessage (workerMain.js:13)
    at s.onmessage (workerMain.js:13)
```

How do I get rid of these errors?

Comment: How do you combine the code completion results? Do you call into Monaco TS completion from your completion provider?

Comment: those errors don't show up if you set `allowNonTsExtensions: true`, but I don't know if this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed by keeping the existing compiler options, and only overwriting the relevant properties. Like this:

```js
const compilerOptions = monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.getCompilerOptions();
  
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
  ...compilerOptions,
  noLib: true,
});
```